# Normalize string with embedded digits

Tags: java, regex

I have a number of folders (200+) which are formatted with characters intermixed with numbers, such as:

```
california1
california2_scenes
california11
california12_people
utah8
utah3_tounament
```

The naming follows the following convention:

- Starts with strings
- Follows by 1 or 2 digits
- Optionally followed by underscore and other characters (no digits this time)

I am writing a Java command tool to rename them in a more uniform way by zero padding the

```
california01
california02_scenes
california11
california12_people
utah08
utah03_tounament
```

I have tried to use regular expression to search for a single digit and replace:

```
name.replaceAll("(\\d)", "\\1");
```

The above does not work for a couple of reasons:

1. The pattern matches both 1- and 2-digit numbers. I only want to match a single digit
2. Java does not understand notation of `\\1` to stand for the first matched group.

I have also tried to solve this problem using straight replace:

```
name = name.replaceAll("1_", "01_"). ... .replaceAll("9_", "09_");
```

Again this method does not make distinction between single- and double-digit numbers and it does not work for cases where the single digit is at the end of the string.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String[] as = { "california1", "california2_scenes", "california11", "california12_people", "utah8",
            "utah3_tounament" };
    for (String s : as) {
        //no number behind, number, no number ahead
        String sp = "(?<!\\d)\\d(?!\\d)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sp);
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll(sp, "0$0"));
    }
```

output:

```
california1
california01
california2_scenes
california02_scenes
california11
california11
california12_people
california12_people
utah8
utah08
utah3_tounament
utah03_tounament
```